# Returning to last seen position on an ajax result page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

For my project I want to be able to hit the back button and return to the place in the page where I last was. First off, what is happening? The user is on a search page that loads 50 results each time they hit the bottom of the page.

Whats happening:
I have a search page that first shows 50 results and then loads the next 50 results via ajax call when the user reaches the bottom of the page.

The Problem:
Users want to be positioned on the page where they last left off when they go Back on the browser.

What I'm trying to do:

First,

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
    var lastScrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
    document.cookie = "lastPageLoadCount=" + lastPageLoadCount + ";";
    document.cookie = "lastScrollPosition=" + lastScrollPosition + ";";
    //$(window).scrollTop(0);
});
```

When the user leaves the search page, I keep cookies of their position on the page and how many times the ajax had been triggered. I think it makes sense to scroll to the top just before moving on to the next page, but that seems to give me an incorrect scroll position.

When the user hits Back to return to the search results I want to read those cookies and perform actions nessary to restore the page. If the user previously triggered the ajax twice, then I want to do that again automatically before attempting to scroll down into position.

```
var lastPageLoadCount = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {

    var prevLastPageLoadCount = getCookie("lastPageLoadCount");
    if (prevLastPageLoadCount != '') {

        // below is where the problem starts

        while (lastPageLoadCount < parseInt(prevLastPageLoadCount)) {
            // manually triggering the ajax call here
            loadMoreResults(); // increment lastPageLoadCount when ajax returns success

        }
        // then scroll down into position
        // ...

        // then delete this cookie
        document.cookie = "lastPageLoadCount=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
    }
```

It's not exactly working out. It seems as if the loop is being hit before the page is ready which doesn't make any sense. The while loop is probably being called endlessly while the ajax doesn't seem to kick in. I have enough experience to tell if setinterval, settimeout or callbacks would help me somehow. Overall this just seems like a really bad idea.

:(

Comment: can you provide some other part of the code?

Answer (score 1):

1. Be sure that the ajax search script does not override values when user go through pages, in case the search script run on every page give some sort of **unique identifier** together with the last position value. ex ( `setCookie({ id : my-unique-page-name , offset : 0, limit : 50 })` )
2. when user hit **"load more results**" keep track of the position and increment the LIMIT and OFFSET values ( if you start with 50 then your SQL query will be something like `SELECT * FROM blah WHERE blah LIMIT 0, 50` ) the next will be `SELECT * FROM blah WHERE blah LIMIT 50, 100` and so on.
3. from your code i see `//increment lastPageLoadCount when ajax returns success` this is useless. just  track it from point 2.
4. from your code i see `while (` that is not needed
5. also consider to keep track of the offset DOM position `$(document).on( 'scroll',` since the unload window event is not that much reliable.

a pseudo code will look something like this :

```
   defaultLimit = 50, defaultOffset = 0;

    on(beforeWindowUnload){
        setCookie({ DOMOffsetPosFromCoockie : ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) });
    }

    // when user click more results
    if (userClickMoreResults) {

        var offset = offsetFromCoockieNotSet ? defaultOffset : offsetFromCoockie;
        var limit = limitFromCoockieNotSet ? defaultLimit : limitFromCoockie;

        setCookie({
            id: myUniquePageName,
            // if your code is designed to load results not replacing the previous loaded content
            // ( ex.: you load all the results from 0 to a max viewed in a certain moment)
            // offset: offset + 50, otherwise offset is always 0
            offset: offset,
            limit: limit + 50
        });
    }    
    // when page load
    if (myUniquePageName == myUniquePageIDFromCoockie){    
        if (limitFromCoockieNotSet && offsetFromCoockieNotSet) {
            loadAjaxResults(defaultLimit, defaultOffset);
        } else {
            loadAjaxResults(limitFromCoockie, offsetFromCoockie);
        }
       setInterval(function(){
         $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: DOMOffsetPosFromCoockie}, 2000);
       },200);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry to say, this doesn't answer the problem.

Comment: @Peter Mercury: please see the updated answer and let me know.